# How to write this regex?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace all characters except letters, numbers and some special characters with whitespace. This is the line of code I'm using:

```
documentText = Regex.Replace(documentText, @"^((?![a-zA-Z0-9%\-\@\$&']).*)$", " ");
```

It doesn't work. I tested it on a sample text like this:

```
[]\^|+*(){} ~#%=/<>-!@$&_'",.?;:
this should stay
```

and it removes everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9%\-@$&']
```

Using `^` inverts the character class, which is perfect for what you're looking for without using a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

you're searching for .* which means 0 or more of any character....that's why it's removing everything.